# Which has precedence in Cobbler, profile or preeseed?

Tags: server, cobbler

For Cobbler on Ubuntu 12.04 server regarding the network configuration (or any settings for that matter) which has precedence during the PXE install - the profile (cobbler system add ...) or the preseed file?

The question then is why?

Comment: Close-Voter(s): this is definitely about Ubuntu.

Comment: Now that I think about it - its more of a cobbler question - not exclusive to Ubuntu - shouldn't it be on serverfault?

Comment: I cannot say if you would get better answers there - but my stance is it is on-topic here.

Comment: @JeremyHajek If you want you can get your question migrated to SF. Just go to [chat] or flag your own question for Moderator attention.